How to allocate array in C when the size is unknown?
I am working on a C program where I need to initialize an array that will be filled with numbers during the program's running. However, I do not know in advance how many numbers will be added to this array.
Initialization: Should I initialize the array with a fixed, arbitrarily large size, or is there a better approach to handle this scenario? For example, if I anticipate that the array might need to store up to 50 numbers, should I initialize it with this size?
Alternatives: Are there alternative data structures or methods in C that would be more suitable for this purpose
edit: further explanation by example
I come from a Python background, so I thought I could initialize an empty array [] and then fill it as needed, but this isn't available in C. For example, in a script counting the number of characters in each word given a string of sentences, I don't know with which number to initialize the array because I can't estimate the number of words that will be inputted.

You can anticipate a likely size, and then realloc() when full, to perhaps twice its size. But beware of using pointers to the elements of the memory block, because its location might change. Consider also using linked lists, allocating memory for each node, but it depends on how you want to use it.

Typically, other data structure libraries for arrays or lists use the notion of "capacity", which is some value larger than what is currently stored. As you read in more numbers and get closer to capacity, you then allocate a new array with (for example) double the capacity, copy over the values from the old array to the new array, and then deallocate the old array to clean up memory usage.

Note that realloc (if successful in allocating the new memory size) handles copying the contents of the original memory block if needed.

@Omar, "However, I do not know in advance how many numbers will be added to this array."  --> In C, array sizes cannot change once the array is defined - comes into existence.  Do you really need the array before the array size is determined?

Just as a hint for self-learning: Do some research on "linked lists" and use such, if it is appropriate to your problem case. This is pretty sure the algorithm used by Python.

Also one main difference between C and higher level languages is that C deals hands-on with the limitations encountered in the real world where computers exist. There exists no "unknown amount of things" because a computer cannot allocate an unknown/endless amount of memory. And even if you have gigabytes available, you probably don't want some plain and boring array to allocate anywhere near that amount. So you can't design computer program like that; there will always be an upper limit as per the application specification.

While this may veer into opinion territory, if you are not very constrained for memory, and you only need to store 50 "numbers" which likely means 64-bits at most for each, then simply allocate that array statically or with automatic storage duration and keep track of how many numbers are entered.
#define MAX_NUMBERS 50

double numbers[MAX_NUMBERS];

If it's potentially much more, then your best bet is probably to dynamically allocate with malloc or calloc and then grow via realloc. To minimize the number of reallocations needed, you should probably grow by:

A factor of 1.5
A factor of 2
or, by a large block size

You'll need to check that your allocations and reallocations succeeded. A common pitfall is assigning the result of realloc directly to your original variable before checking if it succeeded. This is a recipe for dangling pointers.
E.g.
#define GROWTH 2

size_t cap = 4;

int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * cap);
cap *= GROWTH;
arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * cap);
// if realloc failed, the original memory is no longer addressable

vs.
#define GROWTH 2

size_t cap = 4;

int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * cap);

int *new_arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * cap * GROWTH);
if (new_arr) {
    cap *= GROWTH;
    arr = new_arr;
}
else {
    // error handling
}


I would just like to note for the sake of beginners that malloc, calloc, and realloc are functions from the stdlib.h library, therefore it's necessary to include it to use them.

Edited to link to documentation on those functions.

Unlike Python, arrays in C have a fixed length. There is no such thing as auto extend or .append in C; once the array is declared, its size cannot be changed.Maybe that's why c is fast

@Omar Python hides the nitty gritty details from you so you don't have to worry about managing them yourself. Dynamic allocation and reallocation when space runs out is fundamentally how things like Python lists work. You just don't see it.

I know this is how things work under the hood in Python, and I know it hides those complex details as a high-level language. What I was asking is how to apply this methodology in C!
